# Multiple inserts with composite type

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, sql-insert

Consider the following schema

```
CREATE TYPE episode_id AS
(
    season_nr int,
    episode_nr int,
    show_id bigint
);

CREATE TABLE episodes
(
    id episode_id primary key,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    release_date timestamptz null
);
```

I want to insert to multiple rows in one query;

```
insert into episodes (id.season_nr, id.episode_nr, id.show_id, title, release_date)
values 
(1, 1, 58811, 'Pilot', null),
(1, 2, 58811, 'Vector', null),
(1, 3, 58811, '274', null),
(1, 4, 58811, 'Single Strand', null),
(1, 5, 58811, 'The White Room', null);
```

It throws:

```
> ERROR: multiple assignments to same column "id" SQL state: 42601
```

My client library does not support `ROW` syntax. How could I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper syntax:

```
INSERT INTO episodes (id, title, release_date)
VALUES 
((1, 1, 58811), 'Pilot', null),
((1, 2, 58811), 'Vector', null);
```

You cannot reference individual attributes of `id` in the column list of an `INSERT` statement, just the *whole* column.

The added parentheses make a row type / composite type out of the three values.